# How to display pdf content inside fancybox as pdf document in rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation, fancybox-2, pdfkit

I am using fancybox in my rails applicaiton , I want to display server side pdf response in fancybox ,but I am not sure how to do this .

I did the like this

I am reading pdf file data and sending pdf response from server , on view I need to display this pdf response in fancybox how to do this .

or any alternate way that I can show a pdf in fancybox instead download pdf from the server when requesting server.

```
###my_controller.rb

def show
  @pdf_data = File.open(doc.image).read.force_encoding('BINARY')
  format.js {}
end
```

From the above line it states that I am reading pdf file data(doc.image  refers location of the pdf file) , Now I need to display this pdf content in fancy box ,so I did like the following on the view side

```
## show.js.erb

$("#pdfview").html("<%= @pdf_data %>")
$("#inline").trigger('click')
```

I applied fancybox() for #inline which is id of anchor tag.

Can anyone help me how to do this or any alternate that I can make pdf from server pdf response within the fancybox in jquery or javascript?

Comment: Aren't you complicating things? Do you have to server the pdf document via rails? why not just storing the document on the server and reading it from there via iframe in fancybox? see http://jsfiddle.net/9rLkw17e/

Comment: I have a requirement that I need  to keep pdf documents safe , means it should not be find in browser download history and should not download when user clicks browser forward button once after file is downloaded that is the reason I chosen this way , if I could create a pdf with server response(string data) then that satisfies my requirement. please share me if you have any ideas

Comment: Re: keeping pdf documents safe and not findable on the server, I agree with that but once the document has been rendered by the browser, there is not too much you can do to keep the file from being downloaded. The only possible solution I can see is displaying the PDF file as an image like what Google drive does, but still a snapshot of the file will be available to download.

Comment: @JKF there is no chance of document download on the browser side , the whole pdf content I am storing within variable and now I want to use that variable to make pdf on the view side, I want to go with this approach as all my pdfs are small in size (very little content)